# LinkedIn Company Search API

Tags: python, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I want to check if specific company exist on linkedIn and want to know its employee count.
I had came across with this API.
`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search`

But this is depreciated and returned 404.

Then i found this v2 API.
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search`

But this API is restricted to select developers only.

**Is there any other solution to retrieve such information from linkedin?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Organization Lookup API for this.

Organization Search is needed to find organizations with partial or incomplete information. However for your use case, you can use the Organization Lookup API.

To summarize,

## Company search

Deprecated

## Organization Search

Available to select developers

- [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search)

## Organization Lookup

Available to all

- [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a this third party/unofficial LinkedIn Company API to be reliable and really useful:
https://rapidapi.com/williambarberjr/api/linkedin-company-data/

You can see the postman documentation (which I found easier to read than rapidapi's documentation) for it here:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10812513/UVeGpQqo

It pulls the following variables for a given company when they are available on linkedin:

1. Company Name
2. Company Size
3. Company LinkedIn Url (sometimes the linkedin url you feed the api is outdated and the url that is the result of a redirect is shown here)
4. Country Code Of Primary
5. Primary - full address provided of primary location (typically the company headquarters), another variable is provided with this address parsed into country, postal code, street address etc
6. Follower Count - number of followers the company has
7. Domain
8. Specialties
9. Description
10. Type - Public, Private etc.
11. Website - company’s website
12. Original LinkedIn Url - in case the link you provide redirects, this is the original input you provided
13. Employee Count On LinkedIn - probably the most valuable data point that you can only get from linkedin. This api pulls this data (and all the rest of the data) in real time. So the employee count is up to date as of the moment of your api call which is nice, because that's the whole point of using this api for me most of the time.
14. Industries
15. Employees - Information about 1 to 4 Employees displayed on the company page are also available. Specifically:
16. Employee Name, Title, Profile Link
17. Locations - list of all locations mentioned
18. Updates - most recent posts from the company
19. Similar Pages - list of similar pages (usually similar companies)
20. Logo - link to company logo image
21. Slogan - company slogan when available
22. Crunchbase Funding Info - some companies have limited funding information available, this comes from Crunchbase but is displayed on their LinkedIn company page. The creator of this api also offers a crunchbase api that is good as well if you want info from crunchbase as well.